# Executing 2 transactions step by step at a time MS sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.0.1600.22. My aim is to investigate Read phenomena (like dirty reads etc). I made 2 queries containing transactions which modify/select from the same table. However, I cannot run them from one SQL management studio step by step in one time. What should I do to investigate these phenomenon?

Comment: Wow, it was simple. You should select next command from each query and run it one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that in SQL Server Management Studio.

1. Open 2 windows for your queries.
2. In the first window start a transaction but do not commit it:

   `begin tran
   insert mytable values (1)`
3. In the second window, run

   `select * from mytable4 with (nolock)`

   This will show you the record you inserted in the first window (this is your dirty read).
4. In the first window run `rollback tran`
5. Come back to the second window and rerun the query. The record you saw before is not there any more.